# Displaying pdf files on liferay website (using some sort of viewer)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, pdf-viewer, pdfview

I'm fairly new to Liferay and have recently started working at a place that uses the Liferay platform. Still in the starting phases of understanding Liferay so would really appreciate all the help I can get.

**WHAT I'M WORKING ON:**
I'm operating and making changes on a Liferay web platform as well as mobile application. The mobile application is designed to act simply as an extension of the website. All the views, functionalities that exist on the mobile app are a direct reflection of the website. In very simple terms, the mobile app is basically the actual website but through the lens of a mobile/tablet.

As of late, I've been tinkering with setting up links on a page that are meant to open a .PDF file. The whole idea is to have the .PDF file pop up in some "sort of viewer" as soon as a user clicks on a link. Additionally, the user's current page shouldn't change but rather remain inactively running in the background.

Something like this:
[Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRhRA.jpg)

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR:**
After uploading an example.pdf file to my Documents and Media, I've created a Web Content Display portlet where I've added an "Example" text that links to the URL of example.pdf file. Additionally, I've set the target of my "Example" text link to a pop-up window that should display the example.pdf file for a user.

**THE PROBLEM:**
The pop-up functionality works well and the example.pdf file is shown on the website (desktop). However, it's in the mobile application where complications arise. Theoretically, since the mobile app basically extends the website then the pop-up feature should also function in the app. But I'm not getting any response after clicking the "Example" text link in the mobile app.

**MY QUESTION(S):**
So I've been pondering if i'm going about this the wrong way and if there is some other target I should be setting my "Example" text link to for displaying example.pdf file in order for it to work on both website and mobile?

OR

If there some other in built feature that Liferay has for displaying .PDF files, which would work on both website and mobile app view?

Regards,
Malcolm K

Comment: So, basically, your mobile application is a webview of the portal? What it does is basically to open the portal pages?

Comment: @brandizzi Yes, basically. Shouldn't it then just work on the mobile application as it does on my desktop. 
Or do I need to configure some connection that allows my app to open the mobiles web browser?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, I'm not that sharp with mobile development :) I guess, however, the issue is not on the Liferay side. Can your webview module/app/tool/whatever really display PDF files? Have you tried to display some PDF file with it? Also, have you checked if it can handle "_blank" targets? Those are some possibilities to check. For now, you could add more tags to your question to get more help. For example, which platform are you using? What is the name of the webview component? This information can help other people to check this problem.